# TypeError for Python Project

Tags: python

first time of StackOverflow so bare with my newness please.

I'm working on a draft piece for my school, we're tasked with creating a rental car billing script and I seem to be getting a type error when I run my code through. Here is my source:

```
##1)    Request Rental code:
#Prompt --> "(B)udget, (D)aily, or (W)eekly rental?"
#rentalCode = ?

#Ask a question
#Get an answer

rentalCode = input("(B)udget, (D)aily, or (W)eekly rental?")
#2) Request time period the car was rented.
daysRented = 0
weeksRented = 0
if rentalCode == 'B' or rentalCode == 'D':
  daysRented = input("Number of Days Rented:")
else:
  weeksRented = input("Number of Weeks Rented:")
print(rentalCode) 
print(daysRented)
print (weeksRented)


#Calculation Part 1

##Set the base charge for the rental type as the variable baseCharge. 
#The base charge is the rental period * the appropriate rate:

budget_charge = float(40.00)
daily_charge = float(60.00)
weekly_charge = float (190.00)

baseCharge = 0
if rentalCode == 'B':
  baseCharge = daysRented * budget_charge
elif rentalCode == 'D':
  baseCharge = daysRented * daily_charge
elif rentalCode == 'W':
  baseCharge = weeksRented * weekly_charge
```

Here is the error I receive:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rental_car-customer-data-1.py", line 38, in 
    baseCharge = daysRented * budget_charge
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Any help will be appreciated, I'm extremely new to python. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

typecast your integers in float, ala:

```
  baseCharge = float(daysRented) * budget_charge
```

Comment: This solves the problem but the explanation is wrong. The problem is that `input` returns a `str`. Therefore you have to convert it to a `float` before the multiplication.